# How to use special characters like accented characters in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, character-entities

In HTML, there are character entities to input any type of character. In javascript, they don't work in strings.

I want to compare a string with an elements value with an accent (written in Spanish):

HTML element:

```
<h1>Informaci&oacute;n</h1>
```

JS comparing to string:

```
if(document.getElementById("name").innerHTML == "Informaci&oacute;n")
    // ..
```

The JavaScript doesn't think the two elements are equal. I'm pretty sure I cannot type in a special character like an o with acute in Notepad++ and then escape it in JavaScript.

Comment: You can in fact type the special character into your text editor and put it directly into the JavaScript string, so long as you're being careful to keep the MIME types straight.

Comment: Also there's an "n" at the end of the text in the element you posted.

Comment: @Pointy I know. The word is Información, with an n following the o with acute

Comment: OK well if the straight character itself causes problems, you can try `"Informaci\u00F3n"` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the actual character:

```
if(document.getElementById("name").innerHTML == "Informació") // is that Catalan?
    // ..
```

Comment: But I couldn't type it in the editor. Pointy's comment worked for me. Thanks anyways

Comment: You might need a different keyboard layout, but it's possible to type it in the editor.